# Failure installing meteor on ubuntu 13.04 running from usb on windows machine

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, failed-installation

Admittedly, a strange combo .. but I'm poor and this is the hardware I have to work with.

When running in Ubuntu 13.04 from the stick, I tried the installation command line as follows:
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

All appears to download fine but when the installation begins, a string of files with the same error message appended runs on the screen.

The common error message is:

Directory renamed before its status could be extracted.

Any help is appreciated.

also, maybe there's a better way to get this installed on the following hardware:
CPU: Intel Atom n270@1.6 GHzx2
Graphics: Intel 945GMEx86/MMX/SSE2
os:32 bit

I tried a direct install on the native windows boot .. but no go.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried direct install on Windows, but gave no details - it should work fine. What was the problem? Which version of Windows are you using? You can use either an MSI install or an Exe installer from: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Answer (score 0):

OK..for any other Ubuntu/Linux noobs out there caught up in the same stupid mistake as I was (if any..haha) .. the answer is prefix this command:
$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

With sudo .. soo:
$ sudo curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

The error message is a user permission error from tar.

hope this helps someone else! There wasn't a clear answer to be found but I guessed. :-)
This probably means everyone else knows this...now, me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same thing happen with Meteor while installing via Docker.
Looks like it might be a bug in tar or at least in Meteor's use of it.  I found that adding the [--absolute-names](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-tar/2004-04/msg00021.html) flag fixed this problem for me.